# contain dates and check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns - `'DateFrom', 'DateTo' and 'Loc'`.
I want to write procedure which will take three params - `'@From_', '@To_' and '@Loc_'` then check if table have two rows where 'DateFrom' from eg first row is early than '@From_', and 'DateTo' from eg second row is later than '@To_' and 'Loc' is correct, procedure will return 1. If not return 0.

For example I have table with rows:

```
+---------------------------+
|    DateFrom DateTo Loc    |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-01-01  2015-01-03  1 |
| 2015-01-04  2015-01-06  1 |
+---------------------------+
```

and I will exec procedure with params `@DateFrom_='2015-01-02', @DateTo_='2015-01-05',@Loc_=1`, procedure will return 1.

But if table is:

```
+---------------------------+
|    DateFrom DateTo Loc    |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-01-01  2015-01-03  1 |
| 2015-01-05  2015-01-06  1 |
+---------------------------+
```

Procedure with the same params: `@DateFrom_='2015-01-02', @DateTo_='2015-01-05',@Loc_=1` will return 0 because 2015-01-04 does not exist in table.
Please for help, thank you.

Comment: I have procedure which works well if there is one row which correct 'Loc' and I dont know how to do procedure which will check many rows, so I hope StackOverFlow Users will help me. I dont expect finished procedure, but advice please.

Answer (score 0):

like this??

```
declare @ct as int=0

select @ct=count(*) from Table_name where DateFrom>@from_date and toDate<@to_date and loc=@loc

    if @ct>1
     begin
       select 1
     end 
    else
      begin
       select 0
      end
```

EDIT 2:

```
declare @ct as int=0
 declare @dateDiff as int=0

    select @ct=count(*),@dateDiff=datediff(Day,@from_date,@to_date) from Table_name where DateFrom>@from_date and toDate<@to_date and loc=@loc

        if @ct>1 and @ct=@dateDiff
         begin
           select 1
         end 
        else
          begin
           select 0
          end
```

what about this??

Comment: Unfortunately not. I added few sentences where I explained why. If in table, for Loc=1 isn't date '2015-01-04' which is between @DateFrom='2015-01-01' and @DateTo='2015-01-06', procedure should return 0

Comment: see Edit 2, @user3271955

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get it so.

```
SELECT TOP(1) (CASE WHEN DateFrom > @from_date AND toDate < @to_date AND loc = @loc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result FROM table_name
```

Comment: Please add an explanation in your answer, it is not a race and not about solving the problem, it is about answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the idea.

Step 1:

I take first row where '`DateFrom`' is early than `'@From_'`. That if '`DateTo`' is later than `'@To_'` `return 1`.

Step 2:

Else I will add one day to `'@DatAUX = DateTo'` and check if there is row where `'DateFrom'` is early than `'@DatAUX'` that I take '`DateTo`' and compare with param `'@DateTo'`. If '`DateTo`' from table is later, procedure will `return 1`, else repeat `step 2`.`